# Elementary functions equivalent to the prime counting function

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Could there be an elementary function $f(x)$ such that

$$ \pi(x) = f(x) $$

where $\pi(x)$ represents the number of the prime numbers up to $x$? (By elementary I mean, functions those are differantiable)

Comment: No, since $\pi$ is not differentiable (not even continuous)

Comment: I think he means is there an elementary function that equals $\pi$ on positive integers.  Which might have poles at other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\pi$ is not differentiable at any point $x \in \mathcal{P}$ the set of prime numbers. So it is not possible to find such a $f$.